# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration angular compile error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

can anybody help me with this problem?

I was trying to separate files into folders

app

- libraries

  - component

    - home.component.ts
- styles

  - home.component.css
- views

  - home.component.html

here is my home.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './views/home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./styles/home.component.css'],
})
```

Here is the error

```
./src/app/libraries/component/home.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './styles/home.component.css' in 
'C:\wamp64\www\angularpractice\src\app\libraries\component'
@ ./src/app/libraries/component/home.component.ts 22:21-60
@ ./src/app/routing-config.module.ts
@ ./src/app/app.module.ts
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:0 ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: Look at your path for styles once again, then on your file structure . Those paths are relative to component not the folder root . Use ../styles for styles array. However it’s not up to Angular guidelines

Comment: still having errors. so my structure is not recommended ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css file isn't in the same folder as your ts file, it is 2 layers above, so the path is

```
'../../styles/home.component.css'
```

The same for your HTML file path.

```
|--libraries
  |--components
    |--.ts
|--styles
  |--.css
|--views
  |--.html
```

Comment: @user1819843 it is two folder levels.  should be ../../